# How to populate field when using .aggregate()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nestjs

I am trying to populate user in response when using aggregate.

This is my code:

```
    const result = await this.lostModel.aggregate([
      {
        $facet: {
          lost: [
            {
              $match: {
                $or: [
                  { name: { $regex: new RegExp(query, 'i') } },
                  { shortDescription: { $regex: new RegExp(query, 'i') } },
                  { description: { $regex: new RegExp(query, 'i') } },
                  categories ? { categories: { $in: [...categories] } } : {},
                ],
              },
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'owner',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'owner_lookup',
              },
            },
            {
              $addFields: {
                owner: { $arrayElemAt: ['$owner_lookup', 0] },
              },
            },
          ],
          adoptions: [
            {
              $unionWith: {
                coll: 'adoptions',
              },
            },
            {
              $match: {
                $or: [
                  { name: { $regex: new RegExp(query, 'i') } },
                  { shortDescription: { $regex: new RegExp(query, 'i') } },
                  { description: { $regex: new RegExp(query, 'i') } },
                  categories ? { categories: { $in: [...categories] } } : {},
                ],
              },
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'owner',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'owner_lookup',
              },
            },
            {
              $addFields: {
                owner: { $arrayElemAt: ['$owner_lookup', 0] },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ]);
    return result;
  }
```

I found that I could use the `$lookup` and the `$addFields:` and that is what I am doing. But it's not working for some reason.

This is my response.

```
[
    {
        "lost": [
            {
                "_id": "63eabf7ba46937e871a173f2",
                "name": "d",
                "shortDescription": "d",
                "description": "d",
                "categories": [
                    "Otro"
                ],
                "__v": 0,
                "owner_lookup": []
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

expected_output:

```
{
    "_id": "63eabf7ba46937e871a173f2",
    "name": "d",
    "shortDescription": "d",
    "description": "d",
    "owner_lookup": {
        "_id": "63ea6caea46937e871a16c83",
        "email": "joakotest2@gmail.com",
        "name": "UserTest",
        "lastName": "Accout",
        "city": "1",
        "picture": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png",
        "pets": [],
        "__v": 0
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

UPDATE:

This is my document in the `losts` collection

```
        {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -34.5462894,
                    -58.4879365
                ]
            },
            "_id": "63eabf7ba46937e871a173f2",
            "name": "d",
            "shortDescription": "d",
            "description": "d",
            "locationName": "DOT Baires Shopping, 3600 Vedia Comuna 12, CABA",
            "pictures": [
                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png"
            ],
            "categories": [
                "Otro"
            ],
            "owner": "63ea6caea46937e871a16c83",
            "__v": 0
        }
```

And here's that user in the `users` collection

```
{
    "_id": "63ea6caea46937e871a16c83",
    "email": "joakotest2@gmail.com",
    "name": "UserTest",
    "lastName": "Accout",
    "city": "1",
    "picture": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png",
    "pets": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have already check and the owner has a valid value and it does exists in the users collection.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I've removed the facet and the problem seems to be in the lookup. Because documents are matching fine

Comment: I've uploaded the expected_output'

Comment: I uploaded the sample json.

Comment: Strange... your query does work fine in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S-J8OTfAYcb). Would it happen to be that the `users` collection is residing on another DB than the one `losts` is in?

Comment: No, it's the same db. I've been thinking could it be a type error? Because _Id is of type ObjectId() but in the json it's a string

Comment: yes. Different types of data will not match. I thought both were strings as provided in your sample...

Comment: They come and go as strings, haven't had any problems with that. Just the native type of mongodb _id are ObjectIds. I've seen examples like this and they work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was with types. They were coming as strings because of the json. And when I wanted to look for the user it wasn't finding it because in mongodb the `_id` has an ObjectId() type.

Solved it by converting the $owner field to ObjectId like this:

```
              $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                let: { userObjId: { $toObjectId: '$owner' } },
                pipeline: [
                  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$userObjId'] } } },
                ],
                as: 'owner',
              },
```